# How can I change the placeholder of global search field in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel-nova

I want to change the placeholder of global search field in Laravel Nova from "Press / to search" to another text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the JSON file located

```
ROOT_PROJECT/resources/lang/vendor/nova/YOUR_LANGUAGE.json // default en.json
```

and edit in this way

```
{
    // ... other strings
    "Press / to search": "YOUR CUSTOM PLACEHOLDER"
}
```